# couldn't find member applyimpulse

Tags: ios, macos, xcode6.1, swift-playground

Not able to apply the impulse, getting an error "couldn't find member applyimpulse" in xcode6.1 osx playground.

Code:

```
func spawnSand() {

    let sand: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sand")
    sand.position = CGPoint(x: random(min:0 , max: scene.size.width), 
    y: scene.size.height - sand.size.height)

    sand.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: sand.size.width/2)
    sand.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.9
    sand.physicsBody!.density = 20.0
sand.name = "sand"
scene.addChild(sand)
}

func shake() {

    scene.enumerateChildNodesWithName("sand") { node, _ in
    node.physicsBody.applyImpulse(
      CGVector(dx:0 , dy: random(min: 20 ,max:40))
    )
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`node.physicsBody` returns an optional. unwrap it before using it

e.g.

```
if let SKPhysicsBody body = node.physicsBody {  
    body.applyImpulse( ... )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following code and let me know if its working..

func spawnSand() {

```
let sand: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "sand")
sand.position = CGPoint(x: random(min:0 , max: scene.size.width), 
y: scene.size.height - sand.size.height)
sand.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: sand.size.width/2)
sand.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.9
sand.physicsBody!.density = 20.0
sand.name = "sand"
scene.addChild(sand)}
```

func shake() {

```
 scene.enumerateChildNodesWithName("sand") { node, _ in 
 let impulse = CGVector(dx:random(min: 20 , max:60) ,dy:
 random(min: 20 , max:60))
 node.physicsBody?.applyImpulse( impulse) 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I had an odd issue with this where .applyImpulse would not accept the CGVector constructor passed into it. I had to separate the CGVector variable, and then everything worked correctly. Also, the physicsBody is an optional that must be unwrapped before using:

```
func shake() {
    scene.enumerateChildNodesWithName("sand") { node, _ in
        let impulse = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: random(min: 20, max: 40))
        node.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(impulse)
    }

    scene.enumerateChildNodesWithName("shape") {
        node, _ in
        let impulse = CGVector(dx: random(min: 20, max: 60), dy: random(min: 20, max: 60))
        node.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(impulse)
    }
}
```